# to many connection for role error in spring simple crud api on fly.io

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, spring-data-jpa, fly

im deploying a simple spring-boot crud api on fly.io, but the server keeps reloading and logging the postgreSQL error  "too many connections for role #myusername" when i look over the monitor.
My app doesn't close connexion to database apparently

Im new to Spring boot i think ive missed something in the config application.yaml

```
application.yaml
    spring:
      jpa:
        show_sql: true
        hibernate:
         ddl-auto: update
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://horton.db.elephantsql.com:5432/**********
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        username: **************
        password: **************
        max-wait: 10000





    server:
     port: 8080
```

the Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM openjdk:17-alpine

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} rest-docker.jar


CMD ["java", "-jar", "rest-docker.jar"]
```

fly.toml

```
app = "apiremplacement"
primary_region = "cdg"

[http_service]
  internal_port = 8080
  force_https = true
  auto_stop_machines = true
  auto_start_machines = true
  min_machines_running = 0
```

ty for your help,

I tried setting different properties in the application.yaml file like max-wait , hikaricp.

Comment: You are using a connection pool (by default) with a size of 10 connections, apparently that is too much. So find out how many connections you can actually make and modify your configuration accordingly.